# Google App Engine Dockerfile error: Unable to locate package python3.8

Tags: python-3.x, docker, google-app-engine

I am using this Dockerfile to deploy to App Engine Flexible environment.

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python 
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade\
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa \
    && add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa \
    && apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade\
    && apt-get -y install python3.8 python3.8-distutils python3.8-venv \
       gdal-bin libgdal-dev python3-gdal  \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get autoclean -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.8
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
...
```

I've been using this configuration for at least a year and deploy to GCP regularly. As of this morning, when I try to deploy I'm getting these errors:

```
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package python3.8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8'
E: Unable to locate package python3.8-distutils
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8-distutils'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8-distutils'
E: Unable to locate package python3.8-venv
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8-venv'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8-venv'
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
&& apt-get install -y software-properties-common     
&& add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa     
&& add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa     
&& apt-get -y update 
&& apt-get -y upgrade    
&& apt-get -y install python3.8 python3.8-distutils python3.8-venv        gdal-bin libgdal-dev python3-gdal      
&& apt-get autoremove -y     
&& apt-get autoclean -y     
&& apt-get clean     
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 100
```

I'm not sure I want to change my Python version, since some of the packages use Python3.8.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Not sure if this could be with GAE but maybe with the base image. Which one are you using?

Comment: Is the base image the same as the repository? I use ubuntugis and deadsnakes.

Comment: The base image is what you set in the `FROM` section

Comment: FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I was using Ubuntu 16.04 and deadsnakes was no longer supporting Python3.8. See https://github.com/deadsnakes/issues/issues/195

I changed Docker to use `FROM ubuntu:bionic` and that allowed Docker to install Python3.8.

Comment: how did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's documentation, you also need to add a Dockerfile in the same directory that contains the `app.yaml` file. For building Python containers, Google provides this base image:

[image]

The Python runtime has Python 2.7.9 and Python 3.7.2 pre-installed. You can customize the Dockerfile to install other versions or alternative interpreters if needed.
You can specify whether to use Python 2 or Python 3 in your application's Dockerfile when creating the virtual environment:

> ## Python 3
>
> RUN venv /env -p python3.7

> ## Python 2 (implicit)
>
> RUN virtualenv /env

> ## Python 2 (explicit)
>
> RUN virtualenv /env -p python2.7

Here is some more information regarding [Python Runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TbDb.png), [App Engine flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible), [Python 3 Runtime Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime).

Comment: Everything has been working fine until today. I've used the same configuration for at least a year and deploy regularly. I'm not sure if this info affects this answer.

Comment: Do you have `theadsafe` in your `app.yaml`  file? If yes, please remove it and try to deploy it again.

Comment: No, there was no  theadsafe in app.yaml.

Comment: What is the version of pip that you are running? When was the last time you updated pip? Can you try to update it?

`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install python3-pip`